# how to limit user storage space php

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out the best way to limit a user's storage space on my php based app. I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542770/how-to-create-a-solution-that-limits-user-storage-in-an-app) but it doesn't seem to be an optimal way to handle this problem. The answers for that question suggest running a mysql SUM command to get the space a user is currently using. Is this efficient? What do other people usually do?

My case involves storing images for users. The images are loaded onto a cloud storage provider and I keep a record of the file size and name in my local database. Let's say that the maximum space a user gets is 10 GB. If each image is 300 kb after compression, that would be ~33,000 images per user. If there are 1,000 users, that would be ~33,000,000 images and thus ~33,000,000 rows in a table. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178441/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-sum-in-mysql) suggests that the sum command is kinda slow when that many rows are considered.

Another option I thought of would be to increment and decrement a counter value every time an image is uploaded or deleted, but this might run into consistency and syncing problems. hm...

Comment: And your question is? If it's another question again about *the best* way of etc. pp., take note that you should use the tool that suits you best. That can be pretty independent to what others share as their opinion.

Comment: The link you posted about efficiency does say such a sum will be slow, but several of the answers suggest ways to mitigate that. Realistically, though, what alternative do you have? Walking the filesystem on a remote cloud storage server will probably not work.

Comment: I guess there isn't a better alternative. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think incrementing and decrementing a counter value# will be the solution. To ensure consistency, you can run a cronjob to query a slave database and sync the value at a certain period of time (or run the script when you are maintaining the database). I follow this way, for now, and so far so good.

Comment: Ah, that is a good point about a periodic cronjob to sync up the values. thanks